# JavaFX Custom Control main method

Tags: java, javafx

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yuaJQJ1FXg) tutorial regarding custom control creation using JavaFX. I noticed that they had a main method, but they never showed it in the video.

I couldn't export my jar as a runnable jar because I needed a main class, so I tried to create one (code below). However, when I tried to import it into SceneBuilder, it didn't show.

Main class:

```java
package controls;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage s) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MessageTab.fxml"));
        s.setScene(new Scene(root));
        s.show();
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

When I ran the jar in eclipse, it displayed the fxml file.
I want to use this jar as a custom control, not an application, but I couldn't find anything about what I needed to do to export it properly. If you know what I need to do, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: The project for your custom control does not need a main class or method. The reason why your custom control is not showing in Scene Builder must be something else.

Comment: It works now! According to [this page](https://github.com/gluonhq/scenebuilder/issues/256), the issue was that I compiled the custom control using Java12 and open jfx 12, so I simply had to recompile my project using java 8. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Okay, good. jdk-11.0.2 and javafx-sdk-11.0.2 will work in Scene Builder 11.0.0 as well. Good luck.